# MongoDb and String

Tags: python, mongodb

How can i put a string into mongodb?

I have the following String (formatted as JSON but its a whole string)

```
{"file_name": "König_CMP-SATAPCI11_-_SATA_PCI-controllerkaart", specs: [{"Verbinding met pc":"PCI Express"},{"Type controller":"Serial ATA"},{"VerpakkingVerpakkingDe verpakking geeft aan waarin het product word aangeleverd.":"Box"},{"Platform":"PC-Software"},{"Model":"CMP-SATAPCI11 - SATA PCI-controllerkaart"},{"Gewicht":"118 g"},{"Afmetingen inclusief verpakking":"12,2 x 3,6 x 20,2 cm (lxbxh)"},{"Artikelnummer":"CMP-SATAPCI11"},{"Release datum":"2013"},{"EAN":"5412810092369"}]}
```

how can i put this into MongoDB?
if i try to put it in like this is gives me the error:

```
TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment
```

**EDIT**

---

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mongodb.py", line 80, in <module>
    getitem1(text)
  File "mongodb.py", line 51, in getitem1
    collection.insert(text_file_doc)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pymongo/collection.py", line 409, in insert
    gen(), check_keys, self.uuid_subtype, client)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pymongo/collection.py", line 386, in gen
    doc['_id'] = ObjectId()
TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment
```

**CODE**

```
text_file_doc = "{\"file_name\": \""+ titles+ "\", specs: ["

text_file_doc += #while loop that adds elements

client = MongoClient('HOST', HOST)
db = client.Products
collection = db.files
collection.insert(text_file_doc)
```

**EDIT 2**

---

```
while x <= len(cntent)-1:
    test = str(cntent[x])
    test = strip_tags(test).replace("\n", "")
    content = startsoup.findAll("td", {"class": "specs_descr"})
    test2 = str(content[x])
    text_file_doc+= "{\"" + strip_tags(test).replace("\n", "") +"\":\""
    invoer =  strip_tags(test2).replace("\n", "")
    invoer = invoer.strip()
    text_file_doc+= invoer +"\"}"
    if x != len(cntent)-1:
        text_file_doc += ","
    x+=1
text_file_doc += "]}"

class MLStripper(HTMLParser):
    def __init__(self):
        self.reset()
        self.fed = []
    def handle_data(self, d):
        self.fed.append(d)
    def get_data(self):
        return ''.join(self.fed)

def strip_tags(html):
    s = MLStripper()
    s.feed(html)
    return s.get_data()
```

Excuse me for the ugly coding, i have not yet finished polishing it up.

Comment: can you add the code you tried that raises the exception?

Comment: If you can give full traceback, then it will be helpful.

Comment: code and exception added, code is a part which i think gives you the  right idea if all of the code is needed ill hear it

Comment: I think you  have commented out the important part that causes the issue. Your code is somewhere trying to perform an in-place update on a string literal `str`.

Comment: @BatScream While loop is added the only parts missing now is the `request` to get the Html and the find for a specific `<td>`

Answer (score 0):

PyMongo API expects instances of dict (or a subclass), not JSON strings. Please see [the tutorial](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/tutorial.html#documents).

Here's an example using your dict from above (*not* the string):

```
>>> collection.insert({"file_name": "König_CMP-SATAPCI11_-_SATA_PCI-controllerkaart",    "specs": [{"Verbinding met pc":"PCI Express"},{"Type controller":"Serial ATA"},{"VerpakkingVerpakkingDe verpakking geeft aan waarin het product word aangeleverd":"Box"},{"Platform":"PC-Software"},{"Model":"CMP-SATAPCI11 - SATA PCI-controllerkaart"},{"Gewicht":"118 g"},{"Afmetingen inclusief verpakking":"12,2 x 3,6 x 20,2 cm (lxbxh)"},{"Artikelnummer":"CMP-SATAPCI11"},{"Release datum":"2013"},{"EAN":"5412810092369"}]})
ObjectId('5489d5effa5bd820b20f085b')
>>> collection.find_one()
{u'file_name': u'K\xf6nig_CMP-SATAPCI11_-_SATA_PCI-controllerkaart', u'_id': ObjectId('5489d5effa5bd820b20f085b'), u'specs': [{u'Verbinding met pc': u'PCI Express'}, {u'Type controller': u'Serial ATA'}, {u'VerpakkingVerpakkingDe verpakking geeft aan waarin het product word aangeleverd': u'Box'}, {u'Platform': u'PC-Software'}, {u'Model': u'CMP-SATAPCI11 - SATA PCI-controllerkaart'}, {u'Gewicht': u'118 g'}, {u'Afmetingen inclusief verpakking': u'12,2 x 3,6 x 20,2 cm (lxbxh)'}, {u'Artikelnummer': u'CMP-SATAPCI11'}, {u'Release datum': u'2013'}, {u'EAN': u'5412810092369'}]}
```

Please note that keys in MongoDB can not include the "." character.

Comment: i know that, but then how can i create a Instance of dict by using a while loop?

Comment: Python's dict type can be created from a list of tuples where the first element in each tuple is the key and the second element is the value. >>> dict([('foo', 'bar')])
{'foo': 'bar'}